# Parsefloat give output in scientific format in golang

Tags: go, parsefloat

i am trying to parse this string "7046260" using `Parsefloat` function in golang , but i am getting  output in scientific format `7.04626e+06`. i want the output in the format `7046260`. how to get this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {

    Value := "7046260"
    Fval, err := strconv.ParseFloat(Value, 64)

    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println(Fval)
    }

}
```

> ouput :- 7.04626e+06

Comment: You're confusing the formatted output with internal representation. **`ParseFloat` is working fine**. You just need to specify an output format.

Comment: Also, as you're using IEE-754, you also need to check for `NaN` (using `math.IsNaN`)

Answer (score 0):

> Parsefloat give output in scientific format in golang
>
> i am trying to parse this string "7046260" using Parsefloat function in golang , but i am getting output in scientific format 7.04626e+06. i want the output in the format 7046260

- You're confusing the floating-point value's (default) formatted output with its internal representation.
- **`ParseFloat` is working fine**.
- You just need to specify an output format:

  - [See the `fmt` package documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/).
  - Use `Printf` to specify a format-string.
  - Use the format `%.0f` to instruct Go to print the value as-follows:

    - `%` marks the start of a placeholder.
    - `.` denotes *default width* (i.e. don't add leading or trailing zeroes).
    - `0` denotes zero radix precision (i.e. don't print any decimal places, even if the value has them)
    - `f` denotes the end of the placeholder, and that the placeholder is for a *floating-point* value.

I have a few other recommendations:

- Local variables in Go should use `camelCase`, not `PascalCase`. [Go does not encourage the use of `snake_case`](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#names).
- You should check `err != nil` after each `nil`-returning function returns and either fail-fast (if appropriate), pass the error up (and optionally log it), or handle it gracefully.
- When working with floating-point numbers, you should be aware of `NaN`'s special status. The `IsNaN` function is the *only* way to correctly check for `NaN` values (because `( aNaNValue1 == math.NaN ) == false`).

  - The same applies in all languages that implement IEEE-754, including Java, JavaScript, C, C#.NET and Go.

Like so:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "math"
    "log"
)

func main() {

    numberText := "7046260"
    numberFloat, err := strconv.ParseFloat(numberText, 64)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if math.IsNaN(numberFloat) {
        log.Fatal("NaN value encountered")
    }

    fmt.Printf("%.0f",numberFloat)
    fmt.Println()

}
```

Comment: what if numberText = "7046260.12345678" and i want finally numberFloat = 7046260.12345678

Comment: i don't know digit will be in float part and i want to finally parse the same as float

Comment: @AbhirajRoy Please read the documentation for `fmt`: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/